# Call to undefined function get_header() error

Tags: php, wordpress

i just transfered my template to the web hosting, and now i'm getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/a3275045/public_html/index.php on line 2

and my index.php source code is:

```
<?php 
get_header();?>

<?php
    $get_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $weblusive_sidebar_pos = isset( $get_meta['_weblusive_sidebar_pos'][0]) ? $get_meta["_weblusive_sidebar_pos"][0] : 'full';

    get_template_part( 'library/includes/page-head' ); 
?>
<div id="content">
    <div class="page-banner">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-box">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
               <div class="col-md-9 blog-side">
                    <?php 
                        $temp = $wp_query;
                        $wp_query= null;
                        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                        $pp = get_option('posts_per_page');
                        $wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.$pp.'&paged='.$paged);           
                        get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
                        wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'orbit7' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); 
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php  get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and maybe give your question a good edit.

Comment: you can add your code here ..

Comment: `get_headers()` is a native PHP function, but not `get_header()` so is this a typo, or have you a `get_header()` function in a file you've not included?

Comment: @MarkBaker Based on the Pastebin i'd say this is a Wordpress plugin

Comment: Mark baker, now i get these errors.
Warning: get_headers() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/a3275045/public_html/index.php on line 2

Free Web Hosting

PHP Error Message

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post_custom() in /home/a3275045/public_html/index.php on line 5

Comment: See the answer `Generally this happens when someone has mistakenly put index.php from a theme in the WP install folder, where it overwrites the index.php that is the main WordPress file.

That is, the index.php that lives in the root directory (thats the directory with the wp-config.php in it) is NOT an editable theme file.` against the linked duplicate question